# Nginx two locations executed on one request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-ingress

With below nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 2022;
  location /STFlow/ {
    rewrite ^/STFlow(.*)$ $1 last;
    proxy_pass http://zuul-proxy:8080; 
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location / {
    set $realip $remote_addr;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)") {
        set $realip $1;
    }
    proxy_pass http://zuul-proxy:8080; 
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
  }
```

with executing
`curl http://okd-dev-route.internal.com/STFlow/dashboard`

I get following logs:

```
2020/07/16 07:38:39 [notice] 31#31: *1 "^/STFlow(.*)$" matches "/STFlow/dashboard", client: 10.129.4.1, server: , request: "GET /STFlow/dashboard HTTP/1.1", host: "okd-dev-route.internal.com"
2020/07/16 07:38:39 [notice] 31#31: *1 rewritten data: "/dashboard", args: "", client: 10.129.4.1, server: , request: "GET /STFlow/dashboard HTTP/1.1", host: "okd-dev-route.internal.com"
2020/07/16 07:38:39 [notice] 31#31: *1 "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" matches "10.221.196.254", client: 10.129.4.1, server: , request: "GET /STFlow/dashboard HTTP/1.1", host: "okd-dev-route.internal.com"
2020/07/16 07:38:39 [info] 31#31: *1 client 10.129.4.1 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
```

I'm a noob to nginx and okd. It looks for me as if rewrites from both locations /STFlow/ and / are executed!

As far as I understood nginx documentation only one location should be selected and executed.

But here we can see two matches:

> "^/STFlow(.*)$" matches "/STFlow/dashboard"

which seems to come from `location /STFlow/` and later

> "^(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)" matches "10.221.196.254"
> which seems to come from if condition in `location /`

How is it possible?

What's going on here?

Is it possible to put some custom debug logs in both locations to see which lines are executed and in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understood nginx documentation only one location should be selected and executed

Only a single location is indeed selected for *serving* a request. It does not mean that there is no "jumping" done between the locations (contexts) while reaching the final location.

This is what the rewrite module is actually responsible for: jumping between contexts by rewriting current URI / repeating NGINX's location search based on the rewritten URI.

NGINX first finds the `location` with longest prefix for serving request. Specific to your example, this is `location /STFlow/ {`. Now it selected it for evaluation.

It sees `rewrite ^/STFlow(.*)$ $1 last;` which modifies current URI to `/dashboard`. The `last` keyword to `rewrite` directive triggers location search all over again based on the now current `/dashboard` URI. Worth noting that while jumping `location /STFlow/ {` to `location / {` the directives from the former are not going to apply. After the "jump", now `location / {` is the one currently selected for serving the request, etc.

The `location / {` has no more directives (no `try_files`, `rewrite`, etc.) that can modify the current URI and trigger searching all over again. Thus it is the final location that will be used by NGINX for constructing the response.

The directives/configuration that will finally apply to serving response is the ones from the final location *or its parent*, *if* the final location is a nested location. Even then, it depends on specific directives. Some directives will be inherited from parent location and some would not. It is a major topic of its own.
For example:

```
location / {
    expires max;
    location /foo/ {
       index index.php;   
    }
}
```

The `expires` will apply for request to `/foo/bar` because it belongs to the nested location `/foo/`.
But if you were to make it non-nested:

```
location / {
   expires max;
}
location /foo/ {
   index index.php;   
}
```

The `expires` will not apply to URI `/foo/bar`.

Array-like directives, e.g. `fastcgi_param`, `add_header`, etc. are counter-intuitive in how they inherit from parent location. They are inherited *only if they are not present in the nested location*.

```
location / {
    add_header X-Foo Bar;
    location /foo/ {
        add_header X-Something 1; 
    }
}
```

With this config, only `X-Something: 1;` is set, but if you were to comment out its line, you will have parent header apply and see `X-Foo: Bar` in the output headers.

Some may call it "bad design" because it leads to a lot of confusion at the beginning.

Comment: thx for your reply, it's very helpful. One thing I still don't understand is why in logs there isn't a line about matching second "location /"? Is there any explanation to it?

Comment: I believe somewhere in the configuration you have activated rewrite log via `rewrite_log on;`. This turns on logging for rewrite module. The location matching is in the core of NGINX itself. You can probably debug which location is selected by things like setting a different value for a header, via `add_header` (but mind the pitfalls mentioned, in regards with inheritance) and then checking response headers via `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the explanation of my problem](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html):

The break, if, return, rewrite, and set directives are processed in the following order:

the directives of ngx_http_rewrite_module module specified on the server level are executed sequentially;

**repeatedly**:

- a **location is searched** based on a request URI;
- the directives of this module specified inside the found location are executed sequentially;
- **the loop is repeated if a request URI was rewritte**n, but not more
  than 10 times.